# Почему делегирование не работает?

Tags: javascript

```js
var message = document.querySelector('#messages-container');
var buttons = document.querySelector('.remove-button');

message.onclick = function(event){
  var target = event.target;

    if(target == 'button'){
    target.removeChild('button');
  }
}
```

```html
    <div id="messages-container">
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл или ишак — одомашненный подвид дикого осла, сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека. Все одомашненные ослы относятся к африканским ослам.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Корова, а также пара слов о диком быке, о волах и о тёлках. </h3>
      <p>Коро́ва — самка домашнего быка, одомашненного подвида дикого быка, парнокопытного жвачного животного семейства полорогих. Самцы вида называются быками, молодняк — телятами, кастрированные самцы — волами. Молодых (до первой стельности) самок называют
        тёлками.
      </p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

1. Выбираем родительский контейнер **var message = document.querySelector('#messages-container');**
2. Переменной **message** вешаем обработчик события и присваиваем ей функцию где первой аргумент объект события
3. В переменную **target** присваиваем элемент на котором произошло событие его можно получить **event.target**
4. Идет условие если оно **true** идет удаление элемента
5. где у меня ошибка ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое.

```
var buttons = document.querySelector('.remove-button');
```

`querySelector` возвращает первый элемент, соответствующий селектору. У Вас таких кнопок много, нужно использовать `querySelectorAll`.

Второе.

```
if(target == 'button'){
```

Вы сравниваете элемент DOM-a со строкой. Естественно, они не равны.

Третье.

```
target.removeChild('button');
```

Кто же так удаляет элементы?

---

```js
document.querySelector('#messages-container').onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if(target.classList.contains('remove-button')) {
    this.removeChild(target.parentNode);
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="messages-container">
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Лошадь</h3>
      <p>Домашняя лошадь — животное семейства непарнокопытных, одомашненный и единственный сохранившийся подвид дикой лошади, вымершей в дикой природе, за исключением небольшой популяции лошади Пржевальского.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Осёл</h3>
      <p>Домашний осёл или ишак — одомашненный подвид дикого осла, сыгравший важную историческую роль в развитии хозяйства и культуры человека. Все одомашненные ослы относятся к африканским ослам.</p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <h3>Корова, а также пара слов о диком быке, о волах и о тёлках. </h3>
      <p>Коро́ва — самка домашнего быка, одомашненного подвида дикого быка, парнокопытного жвачного животного семейства полорогих. Самцы вида называются быками, молодняк — телятами, кастрированные самцы — волами. Молодых (до первой стельности) самок называют
        тёлками.
      </p>
      <button class="remove-button">[x]</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Третье Кто же так удаляет элементы?  я :))))

Comment: @Leks Ну и как? Успешно?

Comment: Ну и как? Успешно? :(((((((

Comment: @ Igor (target.classList.contains('remove-button') проверяет есть ли класс и возвращает true или false

Comment: @Leks Спасибо, я знаю.

Comment: спасибо я хотел спросить правильно ?

Comment: @Leks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: this.removeChild; this это будет ссылка на элемент на котором произошло событие верно ?

Comment: @Leks Это элемент, чей обработчик - `"messages-container"`.

Comment: target.parentNode это будет ссылка на родительский элемент верно ?

Comment: @Leks верно - `<div class="pane">`